# Elm Simple JSON List Decoding

Tags: json, elm

I have a simple structure that I need to be able to decode, but I'm having problems.

My API response looks like this:

```
[{"userId":70, "otherField":1, ...},
 {"userId":70, "otherField":1, ...},    
 {"userId":71, "otherField":1, ...}]
```

I'm trying to decode it as follows:

```
type alias SessionResponse =
    { sessions : List Session
    }


type alias Session =
    { userId : Int
    }


decodeSessionResponse : Decoder (List Session)
decodeSessionResponse =
    decode Session
        |> list decodeSession -- Gives an Error


decodeSession : Decoder Session
decodeSession =
    decode Session
        |> required "userId" int
```

The error message I'm seeing is:

```
The right side of (|>) is causing a type mismatch.

(|>) is expecting the right side to be a:

Decoder (Int -> Session) -> Decoder (List Session)

But the right side is:

Decoder (List Session)

 It looks like a function needs 1 more argument.
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to approach this based on what you are trying to do.

**Edit:** Based on your comment and a re-reading of your question:

You pointed out that the API response is an array of sessions, which means you can just use `Json.Decode.map` to map a `list Session` to a `SessionResponse`:

```elm
decodeSessionResponse : Decoder SessionResponse
decodeSessionResponse =
     map SessionResponse (list decodeSession)
```

**Original Answer:**

If you want to match the type signature of `decodeSessionResponse` and return a `Decoder (List Session)`, then you can simply return `list decodeSession`.

```elm
decodeSessionResponse : Decoder (List Session)
decodeSessionResponse =
    list decodeSession
```

What I suspect is that you would rather return a `Decoder SessionResponse`, which could be defined as such:

```elm
decodeSessionResponse : Decoder SessionResponse
decodeSessionResponse =
    decode SessionResponse
        |> required "sessions" (list decodeSession)
```

Comment: Thank you, I would rather use the second approach, but since the list isn't labelled in the JSON response I can't get it to work.

Comment: I've updated the answer to work against the input you've provided